# wordpress spanish language code return false value

Tags: php, wordpress

On my spanish Wordpress site, I'm using `get_bloginfo('language')` code for getting the language code. It's been working properly for last 2 years. Suddenly it returns the wrong value in the live environment. My local environment is working properly.

My code:

```
<?php echo get_bloginfo('language');?>
```

The above code return below values:
correct value : `es-ES`
wrong value : `es`

I need the result for `es-ES`

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
get_locale();
```

Retrieves the current locale, in your case, es_ES, with low bar.

More info -> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_locale/